# mysql - order by first condition in where clause

Tags: mysql, order-by, like

I have a table consists of the following fields

```
id, name
```

with the following values

```
1, ciro
2, test ciro
3, ciprox
4, other
5, other
```

i would like to get all the values that begin with "ci" or contain "ci" but show me the results before they start with ci and then the rest.

the query

```
select * FROM table WHERE name like 'ci%' or name like '%ci%' order by name;
```

I returns

```
1, ciro
2, test ciro
3, ciprox
```

I want

```
1, ciro
3, ciprox
2, test ciro
```

therefore before the rows in which name begins with "ci" and then those that contain

is there a way without using two queries to obtains the result?

Comment: `order by name` will give you different order (3,1,2) in the result than you claim (1,2,3).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is quite a common problem! A `case` expression helps here. A query something like (untested)

```
select *
from table
where name like '%ci%'
order by case when name like 'ci%' then 0 else 1 end, name;
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube! I edited that in the original question where it was wrong, and promptly did it myself too!

Comment: I also removed one of the likes in the where. Not needed.

Comment: Thanks... I can never remember if '%' means "zero or more" or "one or more".

Comment: `order by name like 'ci%' desc, name` will also work but isn't very intuitive. `order by not name like 'ci%', name` is one character shorter even -- and is completely counterintuitive.

Comment: `order by -(name like 'ci%'), name`  will probably work, too (one more addition to your collection of counterintuitive code samples ;)

Comment: Thanks, I am using.
CASE WHEN (aa > 6 AND bb > 10) THEN 0
          WHEN (aa > 4 AND bb < 7 AND bb > 10) THEN 1
          ELSE 2 END, aa ASC

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ORDER BY CASE` to sort the items in a way that suits your specific purpose.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666890/sql-server-order-by-case) for examples on the usage.

More `CASE` operator info [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/)

Answer (score -1):

You should go for parent-child-query. The child or inner query will  return the sorted set and In outer query just put your condition:

```
select * from (
  select * from `table_name` order by attribute asc) as sample_table_name 
where attribute >=x;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the asker's problem as the exact expression to use inside the `order by` clause is what's crucial here.