# Order By First Condtition and If multiple matches, order by second condition

Tags: mysql, order-by

I was practicing SQL problems at hackerrank.com when I came across the following question:

> Query the Name of any student in STUDENTS who scored higher than
>   75. The Marks field in the table stores the marks for student. Order your output by the last three characters of each name. If
>   two or more students both have names ending in the same last three
>   characters (i.e.: Bobby, Robby, etc.), secondary sort them by
>   ascending ID.

To solve this, I put together a query with the help of this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96446/mysql-order-by-first-condition-in-where-clause):

```
select Name 
from STUDENTS
where Marks > 75 
order by case when substring(Name from -1 for 3) then 1 else 0 end, ID asc;
```

Now I am not sure that it actually does what the question is asking since, I have no idea idea of using `case` in queries. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a `CASE` expression.  (And we frown on questions on homework.)

Comment: @RickJames thanks for your comments. Not a homework question fyi; I was just practicing SQL ony own when I stumbled upon this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong.

```
case when substring(Name from -1 for 3) 
     then 1 
     else 0 end
```

The expression `substring(Name from -1 for 3)` returns one last symbol from `Name` (if exists). Not 3 last as you want...

So the whole expression returns 0, when `Name` is NULL, empty string, or when the last symbol in `Name` is not a digit rather than 0. And 1 otherwise (when last symbol exists, and it is a digit from 1 to 9).

---

Correct query (looking on your query) is

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Students
WHERE Marks > 75 
ORDER BY RIGHT(Name, 3) ASC, 
         id ASC;
```

Comment: Marks is a field name with integer values that represents the student's marks; marks has to be greater than 75 for the rest of the query to yield the correct result in this case (all students with marks > 75, sorted in ascending order using last three digits of name; if sorting fails because of duplicates then sort using the ID in ascending order)

Comment: thanks for the solution. worked perfectly!

Comment: @AbrarHossain Remember that in my query the records where `Name` field length is less than 3 will be ordered like they have additional trailing spaces. I don't know does it is correct, if not you must add leading spaces implicitly (`ORDER BY RIGHT(CONCAT(REPEAT(' ', 3),Name), 3)`). And the records where `Name` is null will be first, if it is not correct than add previous ordering level by `Name IS NULL` which will move NULLs last.